# Parsing array in PHP having stdClass Object array with key value

Tags: php, arrays

How can I parse this array.

I need to display it as

```
Name : Mathew,
Date:  2018 / 11 / 01,
COUNTRY : USA
```

The array

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object(
                [key] => Name
                [value] => Mathew
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object(
                [key] => Date
                [value] => 2018 / 11 / 01
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object(
            [key] => COUNTRY
            [value] => USA
    )
```

I tried to solve this by using foreach

1)

```
foreach($value as $key => $value ) {
    print_r($key);
}
```

output:

```
keyvaluekeyvaluekeyvalue
```

2)

```
foreach($value as $key => $value ) {
    print_r(value);
}
```

output:

```
NameMathewDate2018 / 11 / 01COUNTRYUSA
```

How can i add the name value to $name date to $date and country to $ country
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you been trying so far? Post the code of your attempts and the issues aou are facing on that code

Comment: check out [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: You have your answer from @alivetodie already. And `print_r()` does not generate output like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `foreach()`:-

```
foreach($array as $arr){
  echo $arr->key ." : ".$arr->value;
  echo PHP_EOL; //or use echo "<br/>"
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/RH4vY

Note:- if you want to save values in different variables then use `list()`

```
list($name,$date,$country) =array_column($array,'value');
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/Zu3Qd

Comment: Thanks .It worked. How is it possible to save the name value Mathew to $name

Comment: Thanks @AlivetoDie .I don't want it in a list. Usually i use  if($arr->key){$name =$arr->value).
I am looking for something like this